# Python implementation of standard Expectation maximization algorithm to estimate position bias in LTR

Tags: python, ranking, bias-correction, reproducible-research, operations-research

Is there any Python implementation that would allow to use logs data of clicks and their ranking, and return and estimate of relative position bias as discussed in section `4.3 Estimation from Regular Clicks` of [Position Bias Estimation for Unbiased Learning to Rank in
Personal Search](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/46485.pdf)?